# JS learning exercise?

Tags: javascript, factorial

So I'm just starting out teaching myself JS from a cheesy textbook and there's a challenge to figure out what this code does:

```
function clunk (times) {
    var num = times;
    while (num > 0) {
        display("clunk");
        num = num - 1;
    }
}

function thingamajig (size) {
    var facky = 1;
    clunkCounter = 0;
    if (size == 0) {
        display("clank");
    } else if (size == 1) {
        display("thunk");
    } else {
        while (size > 1) {
            facky = facky * size;
            size = size - 1;
        }
        clunk (facky);
    }
}

function display(output) {
    console.log(output);
    clunkCounter = clunkCounter + 1;
}

var clunkCounter = 0;
thingamajig(5);
console.log(clunkCounter);
```

For the life of me, I can't follow the logic here that gives the answer at the back, which is that "clunk" will display in the console 120 times. They mention it has to do with factorials (I was never any good with math...) but I can't find the step where the code to display "clunk" repeats that many times. To spare you all the details, every time I walk through it on paper/in my head I just get "clunk" 1 as the output in the console... can anyone hold my hand through this or show me where this factorial part is happening? Thanks!

Comment: Do you understand algorithms in general, functions and stuff like that?

Comment: Notice that `display("clunk");` is in a **while** loop. Read your book to discover what while loops do and how they work. If you only get "clunk" 1 time when running through in your head, then you are simply not taking into account that **the code in a while loop can run many times**, until the condition in the while loop is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because **aviya.developer** has already shared with you how to debug the program, I'll talk to you about the algorithm. I would suggest you study up on programming fundamentals a bit more, because it seems like you might now have a good grasp on how loops work. This algorithm relies on the variables `facky`, and `size` to do the factorial calculation, which we then pass to the `display` method. So you can repeat that for a few iterations and you should be able to start to understand the flow of the program. The factorial part is the while loop in the `thingamajig` method.

`facky = facky * size;`

`facky` is initialized to 1, and our `size` is 5.
The formula for a factorial can be found easily [online](https://probabilityformula.org/factorial.html):

> n!=n×(n−1)×(n−2)...×2×1
>
> 5! = 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 120

- Iteration 1: 1 * 5 = 5
- Iteration 2: 5 * 4 = 20
- Iteration 3: 20 * 3 = 60
- Iteration 4: 60 * 2 = 120
- Iteration 5: 120 * 1 = 120

This is the value that we will call the function `clunk` with.

`clunk` also has a `while` loop, which has a termination condition of `num > 0`. This means we will continue to iterate **while** this condition is true. Once it is no longer true, the iteration will stop.

This means, we will call the method `display`with a value of "clunk" 120 times before the iteration ends.

When you are analyzing an algorithm, it's important to figure out the key components/variables/operations of that algorithm, and keep track of how they change over time or through iterations. This will indicate when the end-goal is reached.

Comment: Yup. I'll just add that to be fair the exercise looks to be written in a confusion manner deliberately. So aside from the factorial issue, it is mainly a manner of realizing the excess code (not reached if conditions)  and dismissing it.

Comment: @aviya.developer I completely agree. They threw in some conditions that would not be reached with the code provided. But, this is somewhat similar to the real-world in that if you were testing an algorithm, it wouldn't necessarily hit every case.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback, I think it was the `while` loop in `thingamajig` that was giving my brain trouble, just as far as understanding how the the `size` and `facky` values change but then circulate back in. Everything else makes sense once that I get that 120 as the number. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

I am not going to go through the code with you. But I am going to introduce you to a method in which you can go through the code with yourself, inspect it step by step, and understand it better.

What i am referring to is the use of debugging. By running the above code with `node inspect script.js` you can run the script in a debugging mode. This will allow you to place little stop signs within the script that will help you analyze what's going on as it is running.

The main stop sign is simply `debugger`.

When you put this in the code, the `inspect` mode will stop at that point and let you access the different variables and methods set up in the script from the console it self. That way you can track what's happening to the different elements and see step by step how the script is operating.

Analyzing it this way will help you understand the logic in a much more profound way and I highly recommend you give it a try.

Here is the script with the `debugger` set up in a decent way:

```js
function clunk (times) {
    var num = times;
    while (num > 0) {
        display("clunk");
        num = num - 1;
        debugger;
    }
}

function thingamajig (size) {
    var facky = 1;
    clunkCounter = 0;
    debugger;
    if (size == 0) {
        display("clank");
        debugger;
    } else if (size == 1) {
        display("thunk");
        debugger;
    } else {
        while (size > 1) {
            facky = facky * size;
            size = size - 1;
            debugger;
        }
        clunk (facky);
    }
}

function display(output) {
    console.log(output);
    clunkCounter = clunkCounter + 1;
    debugger;
}

var clunkCounter = 0;
thingamajig(5);
console.log(clunkCounter);
```

Try it out!

- [Here](https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html) are the docs about debugger.

**PRO TIP:**
You can literally just copy paste the code into your chrome console and it will start the chrome debugger running the script.